# No Data tab or Data Sets toolbox in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How are you supposed to manipulate the datasets in Visual Studio 2010?  In VS 2005 there was a Data Tab (next to Layout and Preview) and a Datasets toolbox.  However in VS 2010 this does not seem to be the case.  Is there any way to enable that functionality in 2010?  I've installed SSDT, but that didn't enable it either.  I'm trying to create new and edit exisiting reports for SQL 2012 Reporting Services.  We just moved from SQL 2005 to SQL 2012 and from VS 2005 to VS 2010.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I can not figure out for the life of me how to edit the dataset querys.

Thanks!
-Brian

Comment: OK I was able to get the Datasets toolbox back by using Ctl-Alt-D, but I still can't find a way to add the Data tab so that you have Data/Design/Preview tabs at the top.